# How many ways are there to arrange a basket with 12 fruits comprised of 4 different kind of fruits with no more than 4 of the same kind

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways is it possible to make a basket with 12 fruits comprised of passionflower, lychee, mango and berries where the number of each kind of fruit isn't higher than 4 ?

So this is basically like having 4 different color of balls in a bin with no more then 4 balls of the same color.

I think we need to solve this: $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=12$ where each $x_i\le4$ using inclusion exclusion principle and stars and bars:

$\displaystyle{15 \choose 3}-\bigcup_{i=1}^4A_i$ where each $A_i$ is a different color.

But now I'm not sure on how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personnally, I would just list all the possibilities, then for each one, count every possible permutation.

Here, you have only 5 possibilities (unless I missed one) :

- 4 4 4 0
- 4 4 3 1
- 4 4 2 2
- 4 3 3 2
- 3 3 3 3

For each one, the number of permutations is easily computable using the number of arrangements.
Respectively :

- $\frac{4!}{3!1!} = 4$
- $\frac{4!}{2!1!1!} = 12$
- $\frac{4!}{2!2!} = 6$
- $\frac{4!}{1!2!1!} = 12$
- $\frac{4!}{4!} = 1$

So the sum is $35$.

Answer (score 2):

Put $4$ of each kind of fruit in the basket, which gives you $16$ pieces of fruit in all, and now ask yourself how many different ways can you take $4$ pieces out to get the number in the basket down to $12$.  This *is* just a stars-and-bars problem, and the answer is ${4+3\choose3}={7\choose3}=35$.

Note:  This approach works fine if the $12$ is replaced by $13$, $14$, $15$, or even $16$, in which cases you're asking how many different ways you can remove $3$, $2$, $1$, or $0$ pieces, respectively.  (The answers are $20$, $10$, $4$, and $1$.)  However, it does *not* work if you change the $12$ to $11$ or lower.  (The answer for $11$ is $52$, which is not a stars-and-bars type number.)

Comment: Can you explain why did you choose those specific numbers: ${{4+4-1}\choose {4-1}}$ ?

Comment: It's not $4+3-1$ on top, it's $4+4-1$.  Imagine $7$ bowls in a row.  Turn over $3$ of them.  Then put passionflower in any bowls to the left of the first overturned bowl, lychee in any between the first and second overturned bowls, mango between the second the third, and berries to the right of the third.

Comment: So the 7 bowls are like the bars, why do you turn 3 of them over ?

Comment: No, the bars are the overturned bowls.  There are $3$ of them.  The stars are the bowls that are left unturned.