# how many ways are there to place identical balls in to urn if each urn has exactly same amount of balls?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, balls-in-bins

I am currently struggling with the question in combinatorics: there are 24 balls, 12 of which are red and 12 are blue, and 3 urns. How many ways are there to distribute these balls independently of their color into the three urns if each urn contains 8 balls?

My answer would be $\binom{24}{8}\cdot\binom{16}{8}\cdot\binom{8}{8}$.
Is this correct?

My problem with my answer is that i cannot distuinguish the red or blue balls from each other so I think I am counting too many possibilities this way. So for example if there are 12 boys and 12 girls and we ask how many ways are there to form 3 groups of 8 people each regardless of their gender the above expression would be correct because I can distinguish between the individual students, right? I would be happy if somebody could confirm or help. Thank you

Comment: Are the urns / groups also identical?

Comment: Yes, there are three identical urns. What difference would it make if they were not identical? Thanks

Comment: How do you know the urns are identical?  It doesn't say that in the question (unless you copied it incorrectly).

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't know the question. I actually posed this question myself out of curiosity, and it's an original inquiry that I hadn't encountered before. At the time of asking, I did not know that this had an influence on the solution.

Comment: Well if it's your question, then you can decide whether urns are the same or not :)  Suppose for example the numbers of blue balls in the three urns are 7,3,2.  Do you regard this as being the same as 3,2,7, or different?

Comment: Would you mind if we consider both scenarios, please? One where we assume 7,3,2=3,2,7 and in the other $7,3,2\neq3,2,7$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  Suppose the urns are different.  Let $r_1,r_2,r_3$ be the number of red balls in the first, second, third urns.  (Note: if the urns were identical, then "first", "second", "third" would be meaningless.)  Then $r_1,r_2,r_3$ are non-negative integers satisfying
$$r_1+r_2+r_3=12\ ,\quad r_1\le8\ ,\quad r_2\le8\ ,\quad r_3\le8\ .$$
Counting the number of solutions here is a standard combinatorial technique which you may well have seen in your studies.

---

So I think now you understand why, ignoring the inequalities above, the number of solutions is $C(14,2)$ (or $C(14,12)$, same thing).  Now let's reintroduce the first inequality, $0\le r_1\le8$.  You need to subtract those of the solutions you have already counted which violate this inequality, that is, those with $r_1\ge9$.  If this is the case, then writing $s_1=r_1-9$ gives
$$s_1+r_2+r_3=3\ .$$
Can you count the number of solutions here and subtract from your previous total?  Can you then work out what to do about the other two inequalities?

Comment: Ah, I see. It's $\binom{24-8+1}{8}\cdot\binom{16-8+1}{8}\cdot\binom{8-8+1}{8}$. So how is this different if the urns are not different?

Comment: No, wait, I am mistaken.

Comment: If the urns are distinct there must be $\binom{3+12-1}{12}\cdot\binom{3+12-1}{12}$. Ahh, now this is correct, right? And if the urns are not distinct, then... let me think

Comment: If the urns are NOT distinct then I have to divide by $3!$, right :)?

Comment: my answer for the distinct urns are incorrect. Because after placing the red balls, I dont know what capacity each urn has left. This is really complicated.

Comment: Just for the red balls, there are $\binom{3+12-1}{12}$ ways. But what do I do with the remaining blue balls? How do I count the ways to distribute them after the red balls are in place?

Comment: Have a look at a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664639/how-many-ways-are-there-to-arrange-a-basket-with-12-fruits-comprised-of-4-differ).

Comment: Allow me to confirm my understanding. If I interpret it correctly, we have a total of three baskets, each with a capacity of eight fruits. Furthermore, there are two different types of fruit. And the amount of fruits available does not matter.

Comment: Answer extended.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed answer of $\pmatrix{24 \\ 8} \pmatrix{16 \\ 8} \pmatrix{8 \\ 8} = 9,465,511,770$ is wildly *wildly* off.

For indistinguishable urns, there are 13 ways.

Consider just the red balls.  If we know where they lie, then we know where the blue balls lie.  Order the urns by the one that contains the largest number of reds, then the second largest number of reds, then the least number of reds.  Actually, $i \geq j \geq k$ where $i + j + k = 12$.

Here they are:

- 840
- 831
- 822
- 750
- 741
- 732
- 660
- 651
- 642
- 633
- 552
- 543
- 444

---

Here's the *Mathematica* code that provides these, once you realize that you must count entries with $0$.

```
    PadRight[#, 3] & /@ 
    Select[IntegerPartitions[12, {2, 3}], #[[1]] < 9 &]
```

This computes the integer partitions of 12 that are of length 2 or 3.  Then it selects only those whose largest entry are less than $9$ (as only 8 can fit in an urn).  The `PadRight` just adds $0$ to each list to make the length 3 (as there are three urns).

If you want the mathematical formula:

$$\sum\limits_{i=4}^8 \sum\limits_{j = \lceil \frac{12-i}{2} \rceil}^{\min [i, 12-i]} 1 = 13,$$

where $\lceil n\rceil$ is the "ceiling" function... the smallest integer above or equal to $n$.

Here's a plot of the discrete configurations for the first two urns, $i$, and $j$.  (The third urn is simply $12-i-j$ and isn't shown.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Stork, for your response. I greatly appreciate your assistance. Now, I am faced with the task of determining the 13 ways manually. I would like to confirm if my assumption is correct regarding the number of ways to place the red balls in the urns, which is $\binom{12-3+1}{12}$.

Thank you once again for your help, and I look forward to your confirmation.

Comment: *Manually*?  Simple.  (That's how I first solved this.).  Start with the most possible reds in an urn (8), and the most in the second urn (4)... 840.  Then decrease the second to get 831.  Again gets 822.  And you're done with 8 maximum.  Step down:  maximum is 7 reds.  Then the maximum for the second, 5... 750.  Step down by one for the second urn to get 741.  See the pattern?  It must stop at 444.  See why?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, because of symmetry we can stop at 444 since the urns are indistinguishable :) (we already counted 354).

Comment: The intricacies of combinatorics involved in my question exceeds my initial expectations.

Comment: @laguna:  Actually you can stop at $444$ because that's the case where the maximum in any urn has the minimum value ($4$).

Answer (score 1):

First distribute the red balls across the three urns. Each urn can contain at most $8$ balls, so the number of ways to distribute the red balls is precisely the number of solutions to
$$a+b+c=12,$$
in integers $0\leq a\leq b\leq c\leq8$. As each urn must contain precisely $8$ balls, the only way to then distribute the blue balls is to fill each urn up to $8$ balls.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then $\binom{12-3+1}{12}$ is wrong. Because I would also count 0 0 12 for example but the urn can not hold 12 balls.